# What does season lock exactly mean in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

While I was checking this [TeamLiquid Site](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Battle.net_Leagues#Seasons_and_Winners) about season dates and more information, I noticed that there is, besides "Start Date" and "End Date", a so called "Season Lock".

What does the season lock do? Does it mean (being in relation to my last question about being demoted in starcraft 2 hots) that from the day a season is locked no demotion or promotion is possible anymore? (Not even if you e.g. lose every match from then on)

Thanks a lot for every answer.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess is during season lock you don't gain or lose points, locking in your ladders until the start of the new season.

Comment: @Lyrion is wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Season Lock fixes your League. You can not be promoted or demoted, but you still earn points within your Division. Bonus pool also stops accumulating for all players.

Your hidden matchmaking rating (MMR) is still adjusting unrestrained, though. If your MMR stabilizes within another League during Season Lock, you will be promoted/demoted immediately after the one qualification match in the next season.

Season Lock is intended to introduce "home stretch" feeling in the end of a season. Because bonus pool stops growing, players who played rarely can catch up on those who used up their bonus pool. League placement Feats of Strength are awarded at season end, so there is an added reason to inch a few places in the Division to gain, for example, a "Top 25" instead of "Top 50".

Answer (score 1):

Season Lock means the League is locked yes, meaning you cannot be demoted/promoted, but you gain/lose Points within your League.